# Connections in Lisbon and Madrid for a Schengen flight - is 1hr too short if I don't have an EU passport?

Tags: short-connections, iberia, mad, lis, tap-portugal

I have two potential flights from Porto to Naples and I'm trying to see if the layovers are too short.

The first option is on TAP Air Portgual from Porto to Naples via Lisbon. I have a 55 minute layover.

The second option is on Iberia from Porto to Naples via Madrid. I have 1hr 20 minutes there.

I do not have an EU Passport (I have a US one). Do I have to clear customs/immigration if I'm flying within Schengen countries? Are these layovers too optimistic?

If none of these work, I have to do a 1.5hr layover in Frankfurt and I know that will be a challenge, so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: The usual questions: are both legs on a single booking/ticket or are they booked separately? Do you have checked luggage? What airline(s) are you considering?

Comment: All single, no checkin baggage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are all intra-Schengen flights, there won’t be any passport control operations. Depending on the specifics, you may have to go through security.

If you book the two legs on a single ticket, then this means the airline thinks there is enough time to make the connection, and they should take care of you if a delay in the first leg makes you miss the second flight (rebook you on the next available flight, possibly pay for a meal or even a hotel if you have to stay overnight...).

If the two legs are booked separately, then you are on your own. If you have checked luggage, you must have dropped your luggage before the check-in deadline of the second flight, which is usually anywhere from 30 to 60 minutes depending on the airport and airline. This means those connections are either completely or virtually impossible. If you miss your second flight, you will be considered a no show, and in most cases your booking and all subsequent flights on the same ticket will be cancelled, so you’ll have to rebook at your own cost.

Note that some low cost airlines never sell connecting flights, even if you order multiple flights in the same order they will be considered separate bookings.

Comment: At most Schengen airports arriving and departing Schengen passengers are not separated. So that means that a Schengen to Schengen connection is just a matter of walking from one gate to another, often on the same concourse. I would expect 10 to 15  minutes to be sufficient.

Comment: @KristvanBesien this depends a lot on the layout of the airport (size, number of terminals, airside transfers between terminals...). In many cases it should indeed not take more than a few minutes to get from one gate to another, but you have to consider time to deplane (it can take a while when you are at the back of the plane), possible bus transfers and of course the boarding deadline, so even in the best of cases it will rarely take less than 40 minutes between scheduled arrival and departure times. And of course that’s only if both flights are on the same booking or without checked bags.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it's a single ticket with only carry on. I didn't realize that there was no passport control for intra-Schengen flights. That makes life a whole lot easier.